# Kerberos - Active Directory Domain Failure (Ubuntu)

Tags: ldap, active-directory, kerberos, samba4

I try to join Active Directory and Samba 4 in Ubuntu 12.04.05.
When I run `host -t SRV _kerberos._udp.test.sg` I get the error:

```
Host _kerberos._udp.test.sg not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

meanwhile

```
$# host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.test.sg 
_ldap._tcp.test.sg has SRV record 0 0 389 4ecapsvsg6.test.sg.
$# host -t A 4ECAPSVSG6.test.sg
4ECAPSVSG6.test.sg has address 10.153.64.5
```

My `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
# Global parameters
[global]
   workgroup = TEST
   realm = TEST.SG
   netbios name = 4ECAPSVSG6
   server role = active directory domain controller
   dns forwarder = 10.153.64.5
   security = ads
   use kerberos keytab = true
   password server = 4ecapsvsg6.test.sg
   allow dns updates = nonsecure and secure
   bind interfaces only = no
   server services = +smb -s3fs
   dcerpc endpoint servers = +winreg +srvsvc
   passdb backend = samba4
   server services = smb, rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate, dns
```

My `/etc/krb5.conf`:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = TEST.SG
    krb4_config = /etc/krb.conf
    krb4_realms = /etc/krb.realms
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true
[realms]
     4ECAP.SG = {
          kdc = 4ecapsvsg6.test.sg:88
          admin_server = 4ecapsvsg6.test.sg:749
          default_domain = test.sg
    }
[domain_realm]
    .test.sg = TEST.SG
    test.sg = TEST.SG
[login]
    krb4_convert = true
    krb4_get_tickets = false
```

My `/etc/hosts`:

```
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  127.0.1.1       4ecapsvsg6
  # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
  ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
  10.153.64.5     4ecapsvsg6.test.sg     4ecapsvsg6
```

What is the solution? Without it I cannot run join domain with command:

```
sudo net ads join
```

which comes out error like

```
Failed to join domain: failed to lookup DC info for domain 'TEST' over rpc: Logon failure
```

I did `kinit administrator` and `klist`, result:

```
   Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
   Default principal: administrator@TEST.SG
    Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
    26/03/2015 14:29:04  27/03/2015 00:29:04  krbtgt/TEST.SG@TEST.SG
    renew until 27/03/2015 14:29:00
```

meanwhile i include my `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
   # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
   #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

   nameserver 10.153.64.5
   search test.sg
   domain test.sg
```

Answer (score 1):

After i google this past week, lucky i found this site http://edoceo.com/howto/samba4

Happens to be i need to edit my dnsmasq (/etc/dnsmasq.conf) 
add this line :

> srv-host=_kerberos._tcp.test.sg,4ecapsvsg6.test.sg,88
>   srv-host=_kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.test.sg,4ecapsvsg6.test.sg,88
>   srv-host=_kerberos._udp.test.sg,4ecapsvsg6.test.sg,88
>
> srv-host=_kpasswd._tcp.test.sg,4ecapsvsg6.test.sg,464
>   srv-host=_kpasswd._udp.test.sg,4ecapsvsg6.test.sg,464

and disable Bind9 (which installed along with Samba4 by default)

Now the problems gone :)

Only one problems remains, how to connect to AD (which i'll open another thread for that)